# How to detect when a dynamic module, and all its dependencies, have been loaded?

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, dynamic-import

Webpack supports the [import()](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods#import-) syntax that conforms to the [ECMAScript proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import) for dynamic imports. This syntax uses promises to asynchronously load modules.

The problem is that the promise is resolved as soon as the specific module is loaded, without waiting for the module's dependencies to load (which can be any type of asset, including JS & CSS).

**Example code:**

```
import('./myModule.js').then(myModule => {
    myModule.sayHello(); // This will be called before someCSS.css has been loaded
});
```

*myModule.js*

```
import './someCSS.css'; // <-- I need to know when this is loaded (there can be more than one asset)

export default class myModule {
    sayHello() {
        alert('Hello!');
    }
}
```

How can I detect when the module, and all related assets, have been loaded? Something like an `onload` event for async assets?

Answer (score 0):

The method returns Promise, which allows you to determine whether a script was loaded or an error occurred while loading (for example):

```
// utils.js
function insertJs({src, isModule, async, defer}) {
    const script = document.createElement('script');

    if(isModule){
      script.type = 'module';
    } else{
      script.type = 'application/javascript';
    }
    if(async){
      script.setAttribute('async', '');
    }
    if(defer){
      script.setAttribute('defer', '');
    }

    document.head.appendChild(script);

    return new Promise((success, error) => {
        script.onload = success;
        script.onerror = error;
        script.src = src;// start loading the script
    });
}

export {insertJs};
```

---

```
//An example of its use:

import {insertJs} from './utils.js'

// The inserted node will be:
// <script type="module" src="js/module-to-be-inserted.js"></script>
const src = './module-to-be-inserted.js';

insertJs({
  src,
  isModule: true,
  async: true
})
    .then(
        () => {
            alert(`Script "${src}" is successfully executed`);
        },
        (err) => {
            alert(`An error occured during the script "${src}" loading: ${err}`);
        }
    );
// module-to-be-inserted.js
alert('I\'m executed');
```

Comment: The promise is resolved when the script is loaded, regardless of its dependencies. See my update for more info.

Comment: @YoavKadosh You have design issue then. These are the dependencies of child module. Parent module shouldn't rely on them. If it needs these dependencies, parent module should import them too.

Comment: They are not needed in the parent module. I need to know when they are available in order to hide the spinner.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use `document.styleSheets` to check when all stylesheets have been loaded. A `CSSStyleSheet` object will contain a `cssRules` property only once the stylesheet has been loaded, so you can create a promise that checks against that:

```
export function awaitStylesheets() {
    let interval;
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        interval = setInterval(() => {
            for (let i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
                // A stylesheet is loaded when its object has a 'cssRules' property
                if (typeof document.styleSheets[i].cssRules === 'undefined') {
                    return;
                }
            }

            // Only reached when all stylesheets have been loaded
            clearInterval(interval);
            resolve();
        }, 10);
    });
}
```